# What do Hindu texts say about sleep paralysis?

Tags: belief, omens

What do Hindu texts say about sleep paralysis?

Are there any stories related to sleep paralysis in Hindu texts? Is it like an omen?

Comment: There is no reference direct or indirect on the sleeping paralysis.
Hindu texts comment only on good and bad karma, paap and punya. Depending upon the nature of paap, manifest in pain or disease or physical handicap or thronging pain (physical or mental pain) pain = result of some sporting activity or falling
disease = longer duration pain
physical handicap = permanent pain or physical discomfort
mental pain = parents losing their only child in an accident ...etc..